# Calculated total and subtotal using field array on redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

With code I gonna provide you how can I calculate total and subtotal on redux form?

```
    const calculatedSubtotal = (detail,quantity,price) =>{

     detail = [];

     const subtotals = [];

      detail.map((detailItem,index) =>{

               detailItem[index].quantity = quantity;

               detailItem[index].product.price = price;

         subtotals[index] = detailItem[index].quantity * detailItem[index].product.price;

        return subtotals[index];

           })

         } 

  const calculatedTotal = (detail,quantity,price) =>{

     detail = [];

      let total = 0;

       const subtotals = [];


        detail.map((detailItem,index) =>{

                detailItem[index].quantity = quantity;

               detailItem[index].product.price = price;
           subtotals[index] = detailItem[index].quantity * detailItem[index].product.price;

         total += subtotals[index];
         })

      return total;
  }


        componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState,snapShot){

          const {change} = prevProps;

          const {detail,quantity,price} = prevProps;

          if(this.props.detail !== prevProps.detail && this.props.quantity !== prevProps.quantity && 
                 this.props.price !== prevProps.price){

            change(`detail[${this.props.index}].subtotal`,calculatedSubtotal(detail,quantity,price));
              change('total',calculatedTotal(detail,quantity,price));
              }
        }


    const valueSelector = formValueSelector('bill');


      const makeStateToProps = () =>{

         const mapStateToProps = (state,props) =>{

                return {

                 detail: valueSelector(state, 
              `detail[${props.index}].quantity`,`detail[${props.index}].product.price`,
               `detail[${props.index}].subtotal`
               ),
                quantity: valueSelector(state,`detail[${props.index}].quantity`),
                price: valueSelector(state, `detail[${props.index}].product.price`)

            }

               }

              return mapStateToProps;
           }
```

I've been mistaken in previous post because I was missing two arguments: quantity and price.

More information can be found in [How to calculate total and subtotal in redux-form using formValueSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230808/how-to-calculate-total-and-subtotal-in-redux-form-using-formvalueselector)

Maybe I'm logging out the input of my functions calculatedSubtotal and calculatedTotal

Comment: What is the issue you are having? At first glance, `detail` is the array, and `detailItem` is your object. But you are using the `detail`'s `index` to access `detailItem` which won't work. Also, at the end of your `calculatedSubtotal`, nothing is being returned.

Comment: I haven't got any issue. I directly can't see total and subtotal calculatings. I can't see the values of total and subtotal, respectively, are calculated by quantity and product's price, respectively.

Comment: If you log out your function's inputs (`detail,quantity,price`), can you add those to your question?

Comment: I just add. I only want a working demo so I can see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: How should be the code of calculatedSubtotal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some assuptions about the shape of your `details` Array, you could so something like this:

```
const cart = [
  {quantity: 1, product: {price: 5.00}},
  {quantity: 2, product: {price: 1.99}},
];

const calculatedSubtotal = (detail) => {
  return detail.map(detailItem => {
    return detailItem.quantity * detailItem.product.price;
  });
};

const calculateTotalFromSubtotal = subtotals => {
  return subtotals.reduce((grandTotal, itemSubtotal) => {
    return grandTotal + itemSubtotal;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(calculatedSubtotal(cart));
console.log(calculateTotalFromSubtotal(calculatedSubtotal(cart)));
```

Comment: It works. Now I will see how can I modify to selector.

Comment: You need to provide more information for me to help you. Can you please add a `console.log(detail)` as the first line in the `calculatedSubtotal` function definition? 

When you run it, what data is being passed to your function? I put this code into a JSFiddle so you can see it: https://jsbin.com/visazas/edit?js,console

Comment: It brings me the cart data. I want to select from renderDetail every fields called detail.quantity and detail.product.price accesing by specify index and when I'm inserting data in those, calculating alone subtotal and see calculated value in detail.subtotal.  For total, the same: When I'm seeing calculated values in subtotal for specify index see calculated value in total. I'm clicking in button add detail, it opens detail form and I have to insert data in quantity and price, when I'm inserting those values, I must see calculated value in subtotal and same for total.

Comment: I must doing that same but in redux -form, in a form. I post code in this post and previous or related.